# Cannot read cell value after adding column programmatically

Tags: visual-studio-2010, datagridview, oledb, vb.net-2010

This is my code to populate my DataGridView (dgProducts)

```
 Try
        con = New OleDbConnection(cs)
        con.Open()
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT Products as [Product] FROM tblStock", con)
        Dim myDA As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim myDataSet As DataSet = New DataSet()
        myDA.Fill(myDataSet, "Stock")
        dgProducts.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables("Stock").DefaultView()
        con.Close()

        Dim col As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        ' col.DataPropertyName = "PropertyName"
        col.HeaderText = "Amount (L)"
        col.Name = "Amount"
        col.Width = "60"
        dgFuelProducts.Columns.Add(col)
```

If I declare *"col"*, I get "Nothing" as dr.Cells(0).Value. But without *"col"*, there's a value.

```
 Dim dr As DataGridViewRow = dgProducts.SelectedRows(0)
 txtProduct.Text = dr.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
```

How can I add a column without having any problems and still be able to read the data when I bind it?

Or please help me find a workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably two-fold.  The data grid and some other things I've found are Case-Sensitive to data binding... How/why/where I don't exactly know.

Anyhow, the datagrid column you are setting the "DataPropertyName" to is "PropertyName", but from your query, you are only selecting the column "Products".  Try changing it to that instead.

By looking at the raw results via dr.Cells(0).Value, why not try looking at the value of

```
dr.Table.Columns[0].ColumnName
```